# Perl regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm having problems with regex conversion from Perl to Python. I have this code:

```
my $str_old = my $str = '$x start $x bar$xy $$x end $x';

$str =~ s/(\s|^)(\$x)(\s|$)/$1\$Q$3/g;

print $str_old."\n";
print $str."\n";
```

and it should output this

```
$x start $x bar$xy $$x end $x
$Q start $Q bar$xy $$x end $Q
```

But I just can't get it working in Python.

Comment: What's is the line of code you've been using in python?

Comment: As says @Jerry, please show your python code

Comment: I got into this state, but it remove white spaces>

import re

str_old = str = '$x start $x bar$xy $$x end $x';

str = re.sub( '(\s|^)(\$x)(\s|$)' , '$Q', str) 

print (str)
print (str_old)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\s|^)(\$x)(\s|$)', r'\1$Q\3', '$x start $x bar$xy $$x end $x')
'$Q start $Q bar$xy $$x end $Q'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, but I just realised that the original regex won't work with string like this "$x $x" (only the first $x will sub). Isn't there a nice way how to correct it?

Comment: @xfrog: describe in plain English what you would like your regex to do, provide example input/output, your current attempt (a complete minimal example): what happens? what would you like to happen instead? And [ask it as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
str_old = str = '$x start $x bar$xy $$x end $x'  # You can remove this semicolon
 # str = re.sub( '(\s|^)(\$x)(\s|$)' , '$Q', str)
 #                                      ^^ You're not placing the spaces back.
str = re.sub( '(\s|^)\$x(\s|$)' , '\\1$Q\\2', str)

print(str)
print(str_old)
```

That said, you should raw your regex string and replacement string:

```
str = re.sub(r'(\s|^)\$x(\s|$)' , r'\1$Q\2', str)
```

And last, avoid using the variable name `str` in python. There is a function named `str` already:

```
import re
str_old = s = '$x start $x bar$xy $$x end $x'

str = re.sub(r'(\s|^)\$x(\s|$)' , r'\1$Q\2', str)

print(str)
print(str_old)
```

If you don't want to use the backrefereces, you can use lookarounds:

```
import re
str_old = s = '$x start $x bar$xy $$x end $x'  # You can remove this semicolon

str = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))\$x(?=\s|$)' , '$Q', str)
           # Since you don't have backreferences, you can now drop the rawing.

print(str)
print(str_old)
```

`(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))` makes sure that the `$x` is preceded by a space or the beginning of the string;

`(?=\s|$)` makes sure that the `$x` is followed by a space or the end of the string.

Comment: @xfrog Since you want it to work for `$x $x`, use the last code block here.

Comment: thank you, it works. I just had to change it a little to: re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))(\$x)(?=\s|$)' , '$Q', s) because of "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" error, now it works correctly. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @xfrog Oh, you're right! Forgot about that with python.